# How to combine same metric probe_success with different labels before averaging?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I'm using the Prometheus blackbox-exporter to capture synthetics and I'm scratching my head on this one.

I have captured data for some urls for several days and I went and added some more labels so now I have two different time series for the same target(instance) but using the same metric name.

As an example:

```
probe_success{instance="http://prometheus.io", job="blackbox-http"}
probe_success{instance="http://prometheus.io", job="blackbox-http", domain="prometheus.io" env="test"}
```

If I do `avg_over_time(probe_success{}[1d:])` I'll now get two (or more) results for the same instance.  As a result, I have two different values in a grafana panel now where I should have only one.

I've read through the documentation and multiple blogs/examples and I just can't figure out what I need to do.  I need env and domain to remain in the result.  I have multiple URLs, some with full paths to health checks where domain is populated from instance label via regex.

Joining seems to work with two different metrics but not the same metric or I can't figure out the syntax.

I would like to preserve the extra fields and have it apply to the full set and I need a solution that will work with ranged vectors so I can get data for several days/weeks.  I'm worried that further changes to labels will worsen the issue.  I sort of got something cumbersome working like

```
label_replace(probe_success{instance="http://prometheus.io"}, "url", "$1", "instance", "https?://([^/]+).*")
```

for the old data but it only works for an instance vector and not a ranged vector.

I've tried to solve this in both Prometheus and Grafana and will be happy with a solution in either one.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 different values because the metrics aren't the same. If you want to combine both you need to drop the extra labels aggregating `by (instance, job)` .
So you can do the label replace that you mentioned before aggregating by.